# Minimum force needed to keep the book from slipping?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, statics

I would just like to know if my answer to part C is correct because I am confident in parts a and b, Also note **that 51.5N is the wrong value for P. P=515N.**
[image: Problem]

Ok so since P= normal force, this means that for part A the normal force is 515N.

For part B, its just Fs=(.255)*(515), which gives me 131.325N.

For part C, its I think Fn=(9.85)*(9.8)/(.255) or Fn=(m*g)/Us, which gives me 378.54N. Now I am not sure if this is the minimum horizontal force needed to keep the book from slipping, since in part b's answer is less?

Comment: Is the book slipping when P=515N?  If not, then the minimum value of P to avoid slipping will be less than or equal to 515N.

Comment: Your doubt about part C is unnecessary. You need to compare your 378.54N with the 515N of part A, and it is less, so everything is all right.

Answer (score 1):

The **maximum** force of static friction is the coefficient of static friction times the normal force. This is what you have calculated as 131.325N.

The **force** of static friction is whatever is needed to counteract the other forces on the book (as long as it doesn't exceed the maximum, of course). If you say that the force of static friction is 131.325N upwards, and the force of gravity on the book is 96.53 N downwards, then the book will fly upwards - which it obviously doesn't! The force of static friction in the question can only be 96.53 N upwards.

Of course, it is also possible that the setter of the question doesn't understand friction and is not asking you for the real force in part (b) but the maximum available force. One way to educate him is to point out that if the book is lying flat on a horizontal table, pressing down on it does not generate a frictional force at all.

Comment: How did you get the force of gravity to be 95.53N? Is it Fg=(9.8)(9.85), if its that then I get 96.53.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are right.

I think there's a little confusion in your thought, that needs to be clarified:

The normal force $N$=$P$ ,which in this case acts  **horizontally** , cannot be compared with the friction force that acts **vertically** , so your query: *"Now I am not sure if this is the minimum horizontal force needed to keep the book from slipping, since in part b's answer is less?"*, is meaningless.

As you have already calculated , the minimum  force $P$ needed ,must cause a friction force $F$ which must equal the weight $W$,so: $F=W <=>P*0.255=m*g <=> P=378.55N$